# Origin of human souls being literally dark

Tags: history-of, souls

So, in *Dark Souls* there is a distinction between Souls, which are white, and humanity, which is dark/black. Humanity is possessed by those who are not hollow.

Now I find that in *TES V: Skyrim*, there is also a distinction between non-sentient white souls, and sentient black souls. I am not aware that this was also the case in *TES III: Morrowind*.

This trope is interesting because normally we think of Ghosts, spirits, souls etc. as being white.

This makes me think there might be a common origin to this trope. What is it? What is the earliest example of "human souls are - literally - dark"?

Comment: Just to be clear are you looking for the origin in a SFF-nal work or the origin of the thing entirely which is likely routed in folklore/mythology etc. and so wouldn't be on topic.

Comment: @TheLethalCarrot I don't think this trope can be too common, at least not in this general form. I am aware that it is common to say some evil person has a "black soul", but I am/was not aware of a trope "all human souls are black". Maybe "all humans have an evil nature", but not "all humans have a literally black soul".

Answer (score 3):

**TL;DR:** The "trope" of "Light/White vs Dark/Black" is different from one to the other. *Dark Souls* uses this more as a physical descriptor, whereas *The Elder Scrolls* uses it as an adjective for morality. Additionally, In *Dark Souls*, yes; it is specific to Humans, in TES, it is not.

---

Firstly, in *Dark Souls*, *Humanity* and *Souls* are very different. For example, the Humanity Sprites found in Chasm of the Abyss drop both the Humanity item, and give you Souls. From the [wiki](https://darksouls.fandom.com/wiki/Dark_Soul) (emphasis mine):

> During the advent of Fire, the concept of Disparity came into existence, and with it the Dark and the Light. **From the Dark came beings (Hollows) who claimed souls near the First Flame**; 4 of these became the Lords who claimed the mightiest and most brilliant of souls. **While the other three "Lords" chose larger souls, there was a fourth, a lowly and forgotten being known only the Furtive Pygmy. His soul was the Dark Soul.**
>
> Using the Dark Soul, **the Pygmy created black sprites of darkness called Humanity, who was given to his descendants, who became the humans. These dark-souled beings risen from the Abyss, called Humans, each bore fragments of the Dark Soul.**

Additionally, without going too much into detail, the act of "going Hollow" in the *Dark Souls* series is tied very closely (or is a synonym for) going mad, or finding yourself without purpose.

So to summarize, in the *Dark Souls* series, The "Dark Soul" is a name given to one of the 4 Lord Souls, created by the Disparity, when the First Flame came into being. The main focus there, being the Disparity of "Light" and "Dark", quite literally. Light from the flame, the sun, and the Dark of the shadows, created by the light. Without light, there is no Dark, and there can be no Dark, if there is no Light.

---

In other games, like *The Elder Scrolls*, the use of "Light" and "Dark" is used differently, to describe the morality of the magic used. As you explain, the White and Black souls are distinguished by their *sentience*. You can extract a White Soul from a dead creature, and you can extract a Black soul from an alive one, and more specifically, it is not tied to a *human* soul, this can be done with *any* creature.

This is where the "Light/White" and "Dark/Black" morality comes in. Trapping a dead soul is merely capturing the essence of the soul, after the creature dies, therefore is no longer sentient. You aren't trapping a bear in a crystal, only the essence of the bear, it's spiritual power. If you did this to a live bear, that bear would remain sentient, and aware of its containment in a crystal. One is cruel, the other is not.

Comment: Just a note, as of the change in markdown engine you need to put the `>` on every line of the quote including the blank lines for it to be rendered as one quote block. I've done this for you here.

Comment: As far as TES are concerned, this is simply incorrect. Creatures need to be killed to be soul trapped and kind of trapped soul depends on type of creature.

Comment: It's been a while since I played TES, but the point is the difference between the Dichotomy and comparison of "Light/Dark" and "Good/Evil" in Dark Souls and TES. If you feel that detail is necessary, please feel free to correct it.

Comment: Well, seems I got "reject edited", so not that free... Gotta hit 2k, I guess.

Comment: @Mithoron The reason it was rejected was because you were trying to explain why what I said was wrong, so what you can do is simply just edit it to remove the incorrect information, and leave in the information that is relevant to the post. Having a high enough rep won't give you the ability to approve your own post - the edit will still get reverted for the same reason.

Comment: Hmm... it could be I'm not remembering a particular sort of lore, but in the Elder Scroll games, regular soul gems could capture nonhuman souls, but it took a black soul gem to capture the soul of a human. So it's not that the souls are black, but that the gem is. Of course, that may vary by game.